# wrong number of arguments and hash issues

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a method that counts the number of times it uses a word from a dictionary and is returned as a hash. Here's my code now:

```
def substrings(words, dictionary)
  hash = {}
  substrings.downcase!
  dictionary.each do |substring|
    words.each do |word|
      if word.include? substring +=1
      end
    end
  end
 hash.to_s
end

dictionary = ["below", "down", "go", "going", "horn", "how", "howdy", "it", "i", "low", "own", "part", "partner", "sit"]
  words = "below"

substrings(words, dictionary)
```

And I get this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
=> {"below"=>1, "low"=>1}
```

I have tried multiple things but it never gives me that hash. I either get an undefined method error or this:

```
=> ["below", ["below", "down", "go", "going", "horn", "how", "howdy", "it", "i", "low", "own", "part", "partner", "sit"]]
```

Comment: Do you intend `words` to be an array? Why is the variable name plural?

Comment: What line of your code gave the error? There was a line number included.... Also you are showing code and saying what t you want the output to be but haven't said what the inputs are supposed to look like.

Comment: @lurker 7: It gave me this: 2:in `substrings', 4:in `substrings' What do you mean by inputs?

@moveson: I named it words for no particular reason, does it matter?

Comment: By "inputs" I mean when you call your method `substrings(words, dictionary)` what kind of arguments to you expect for `words` and `dictionary`? The message `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)` means you're calling a method with no arguments but it requires 2 arguments.

Comment: @lurker I want the first argument to take a word and the second argument to return a hash list of the words in the dictionary.

Comment: Why do you want the output to be a hash when all values will be `1`?

Comment: `substrings.downcase!` seems strange. `substrings` is the name of your method. Ruby thinks you're calling `substrings` without any arguments, which is why you saw your original error, *wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)*. Applying `.downcase!` to `substrings` is obviously wrong.

Comment: @faby Yes, names matter. Ruby convention is to assign plural variable names to Arrays and singular variable names to Strings. For me, it makes a huge difference in how I think about my code. In the case of this example, if you had used `word` instead of `words`, it might have been more apparent that you can't call `word.each` because `word` represents a String, not an Array.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is caused by the line "substrings.downcase!" This is a recursive call to your substrings method which takes two arguments, and you are providing none. If this were not the case, you would still get an error, a stack overflow caused by the infinite recursion of this code.

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the desired result, but I'm exchanging `words` in favor of `word`:

```
def substrings(word, dictionary)
  word = word.downcase
  dictionary.select { |entry| word.include?(entry.downcase) }
            .group_by(&:itself)
            .map { |k, v| [k, v.size] }.to_h
end
```

This results in:

```
>> dictionary = ["below", "down", "go", "going", "horn", "how", "howdy", "it", "i", "low", "own", "part", "partner", "sit"]
>> word = 'below'
>> substrings(word, dictionary)
=> {"below"=>1, "low"=>1}
```

And counts multiple copies of words, which although not explicitly stated, is presumably what you are after:

```
>> dictionary = ["below", "be", "below", "below", "low", "be", "pizza"]
>> word = 'below'
>> substrings(word, dictionary)
=> {"below"=>3, "be"=>2, "low"=>1}
```

Comment: Please check your results. What is `count_by`? There is no method `Hash#count_by` or `Enumerable#count_by`.

Comment: I did check my work...unfortunately, however, the Rails console where I checked it was within a project where I had defined `Enumerable#count_by`. I've gotten quite used to having it around. :) Edited to use the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#reduce`:

```
def substrings(sentence, dictionary)
  sentence = sentence.downcase
  dictionary.reduce(Hash.new(0)) do |counts,word| 
    counts[word] +=1 if sentence.include?(word.downcase)
    counts
  end
end

dictionary = ["below", "down", "go", "going", "horn", "how", "howdy", "it", "i", "low", "own", "part", "partner", "sit"]
sentence = "below"

substrings(sentence, dictionary) #=> {"below"=>1, "low"=>1}
```

Or `#each`:

```
def substrings(sentence, dictionary)
  sentence = sentence.downcase
  counts = Hash.new(0) # Makes the default value `0` instead of `nil`
  dictionary.each do |word| 
    if sentence.include?(word.downcase)
      counts[word] += 1
    end
  end
  counts
end

dictionary = ["below", "down", "go", "going", "horn", "how", "howdy", "it", "i", "low", "own", "part", "partner", "sit"]
sentence = "below"

substrings(sentence, dictionary) #=> {"below"=>1, "low"=>1}
```